# how to place pagination limit per page in rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For instance, I have got a Comapny model. I can get per page limit of 10 in the way as below?

```
class Client::CompanyController < ApplicationController
def company_search
    @companies = Company.all.page(params[:page],:per_page=>10)
end
```

end

Comment: You can use https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari or https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate. Their documentation is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Its not a built in feature and thus the question is off-topic since it implicitly solicits software recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You can user [will_paginate gem](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)
and than in your controller You can put:

```
def company_search
    @companies = Company.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
end
```

and in Your view:

```
# render your companies data with render or @companies.each do |company|
render @companies
# pagination
will_paginate @companies
```